# Rails 3 Relationship between Categories, Subcategories and Items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want to following categories/subcategories/items for my house model.

- Category: Amenities
- Subcategory: Kitchen
- Items: Oven, Microwave, Toaster
- Subcategory: Phone/Internet
- Items: WIFI, Internet acces
- Subcategory: Entertainment
- Items: DVD-player, Television
- Category: Location
- Subcategory: ect
- Items: ectetc

The categories belongs to house/villa’s model. What is the best config (model/scheme) for this kind of relationships?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Item has_one SubCategory
- SubCategory has_one Category
- SubCategory has_many Items
- Category has_many SubCategories

Comment: John...thanks. Do you know some links/docs where i can find a tutorial. Specialy in case of the view/select_tag (nested forms)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [Nested Set](https://github.com/skyeagle/nested_set) to the Category-SubCategory part an reduce some lines, then you have only two models, your principal that I'd call `Category` and the other one should be `Item` then you can easily link your nodes from `Category` with `Item` on an easy `has_many` `belongs_to` association [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) .